# How to call redux-thunk's dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the following action

```
export const fetchCommentRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_COMMENTS_REQUEST,
  };
};

export const fetchComments = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchCommentRequest());
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((comments) => dispatch(fetchCommentSuccess(comments)))
      .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchCommentFailure(err)));
  };
};
```

index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./redux/rootReducer";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const middleware = [thunk, logger];
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
console.log(store.getState());
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

CommentsContainer.js

```
function CommentsContainer() {
      const { comments, loading } = useSelector((state) => ({
        comments: state.comments.items,
        loading: state.comments.loading,
      }));
    
      return (
        <Comments
          loading={loading}
          comments={comments}
        />
      );
    }
```

Comments.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useDispatch } from "react";
import { fetchComments } from "../redux/index";

const Comments = ({ comments, loading }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchComments());
  }, []);

  const commentsItems = loading ? (
    <div>is loading...</div>
  ) : (
    comments.map((comment) => (
      <div key={comment.id}>
        <h3>{comment.name}</h3>
        <p>{comment.email}</p>
        <p>{comment.body}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  );

  return <div className="comments">{commentsItems}</div>;
};

export default Comments;
```

I wanted to call an action using redux-thunk's dispatch. But The issue is when i call this action, I get in the console.

> TypeError: dispatch is not a function

I used useSelector, not connect().
I solved this problem through connect(), but this time I wanted to use useSelector, so I tried and got an error. What do I need to do to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use hooks you need to get a reference to the `dispatch` function through [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch). Also, you can just import the thunk directly instead of passing it via `props`

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import fetchComments from 'path..'

const Comments = ({ comments, loading }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchComments());
  }, []);

  const commentsItems = loading ? (
    <div>is loading...</div>
  ) : (
    comments.map((comment) => (
      <div key={comment.id}>
        <h3>{comment.name}</h3>
        <p>{comment.email}</p>
        <p>{comment.body}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  );

  return <div className="comments">{commentsItems}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified the code and edited question as the answer you gave, but this time I get a new error, TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. What to do in this case?

Comment: @Jay0813 You are importing `useDispatch ` from `react` instead of `react-redux`

Comment: I must have been crazy for a while. Thank you very much for the answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome, Thank you and same to you

Answer (score 0):

First use the `useDispatch` React hook from `react-redux`, then dispatch the action. The `useSelector` hook is for selecting out chunks of your redux state.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Comments = ({ comments, loading }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchComments());
  }, [fetchComments]);

  const commentsItems = loading ? (
    <div>is loading...</div>
  ) : (
    comments.map((comment) => (
      <div key={comment.id}>
        <h3>{comment.name}</h3>
        <p>{comment.email}</p>
        <p>{comment.body}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  );

  return <div className="comments">{commentsItems}</div>;
};
```